# jsprit as backend for php web application

Tags: java, php, tomcat, jsprit

I might be barking up the wrong tree here as I have no experience with java programming.

I came across jsprit a java based VRP solver which looks very impressive and I was wondering if it can be used in a php based web app.

I have installed tomcat and JavaBridge, I have downloaded the jsprit source and binaries.

Is it possible...

1. to use the binaries directly by creating and deploying a `.war` file?

or

2. use the `.jar` files via JavaBridge?

or would I need some kind of java web app to act as a wrapper?

I have seen an app on [github](https://github.com/perliedman/jsprit.web) which looks to be a wrapper but it doesn't look finished or still active.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further research I found the anser myself.

I downloaded the [JavaBridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) template `.war` file and renamed it to `jsprit.war`.

I then downloaded the binaries for [jsprit](https://github.com/jsprit/mvn-rep/tree/master/releases/jsprit).

Using 7-zip I added the jsprit binaries to the newly renamed `jsprit.war` in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder.

Installed and setup `tomcat`.

Installed `php5.cli`.

Using `tomcat` web app manager I deployed the `jsprit.war` file.

Now, by including `http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc` in my php page I am now able to access the jsprit classes using: `$location = new java('jsprit.core.problem.Location');`

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Hi @Gavin Thanks for sharing your solution. I am in the same situation and I need to make jscript work with PHP either through API or any other way which is possible. I read your solution but I don't completely understand as I am not familiar with Java.

Could you please explain how that will work and if it does everything jsprit does? Do I need to know java to use your solution?

How do I call functions like optimizing multiple waypoints etc?

If you could share your solutions with me that would be much appreciated.